Best order of columns in an index based on distinct value count
I have a table
create table t (
    index_column_a integer not null,
    index_column_b integer not null
    value_column_a integer not null,
    value_column_b character varying(256) not null,
    ...
);

Let's say:

the table has 100,000,000 entries
there are 10 distinct possible values of index_column_a
there are 10,000,000 distinct values of index_column_b
the combination of index_column_a and index_column_b are unique

I want to access 10,000 records at a time by specifying:

a single value for index_column_a
a between range for index_column_b

Such as:
select index_column_a, index_column_b, value_column_b, ...
from   t
where  index_column_a = 5
and    index_column_b between 3200000 and 3210000;

Which of the following is a more efficient index for select speed?
create unique index t_idx on t(index_column_a, index_column_b);

or
create unique index t_idx on t(index_column_b, index_column_a);


Why not test with each to see which is more performant? For a general discussion, see How to Use Composite Indexes in SQL to Speed Up Queries. I suspect that the order (index_column_a, index_column_b) will be more performant; however, the distribution of values and query specifics (such as sort order) can affect performance.

yeah, that's what I'll do, but perhaps someone knows why and can explain it. index_column_b is timeseries data, uniform for each index_column_a. thanks

That depends on how you'll query the table. You might want to widen the scope of your question and make it about optimal index+query pair. If you already have a query (or a few) these are meant to speed up, they would be a relevant addition to the post.

I updated the number of values selected, because that is closer to my use case, and that may invalidate previous comment suggestion. Also, I added an example query. Thanks.

The following presents a simple approach to evaluating the affect of column order on the performance of indexes using columns index_column_a and index_column_b.
Setup
Begin by creating a demonstration table and populating it with data that is statistically consistent with the anticipated value distributions:
CREATE TABLE test_rows (
  index_column_a INTEGER NOT NULL,
  index_column_b INTEGER NOT NULL,
  value_column_a INTEGER NOT NULL,
  value_column_b CHARACTER VARYING(256) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_rows (index_column_a, index_column_b, value_column_a, value_column_b)
SELECT n % 10, n / 10, n, n::TEXT
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100000000) s (n);

Testing
Example Query
The following query template is run with each index order with :max_b set to values that will return 10,000 and 100,000 rows.
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE)
SELECT *
  FROM test_rows
  WHERE index_column_a = 5
    AND index_column_b BETWEEN 0 AND :max_b;

Testing with Index Order (index_column_a, index_column_b)
Create Index
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_rows_a_b ON test_rows (index_column_a, index_column_b);

Explain Plans
10,000 rows
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.test_rows  (cost=221.22..33462.80 rows=9149 width=20) (actual time=1.257..3.405 rows=10000 loops=1)
  Output: index_column_a, index_column_b, value_column_a, value_column_b
  Recheck Cond: ((test_rows.index_column_a = 5) AND (test_rows.index_column_b >= 0) AND (test_rows.index_column_b <= 9999))
  Heap Blocks: exact=636
  Buffers: shared hit=667
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_rows_a_b  (cost=0.00..218.93 rows=9149 width=0) (actual time=1.140..1.141 rows=10000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((test_rows.index_column_a = 5) AND (test_rows.index_column_b >= 0) AND (test_rows.index_column_b <= 9999))
        Buffers: shared hit=31
Planning Time: 0.071 ms
Execution Time: 4.176 ms

100,000 rows
Index Scan using test_rows_a_b on public.test_rows  (cost=0.57..380969.20 rows=102570 width=20) (actual time=0.075..31.211 rows=100000 loops=1)
  Output: index_column_a, index_column_b, value_column_a, value_column_b
  Index Cond: ((test_rows.index_column_a = 5) AND (test_rows.index_column_b >= 0) AND (test_rows.index_column_b <= 99999))
  Buffers: shared hit=6646
Planning Time: 0.099 ms
Execution Time: 38.469 ms

Testing with Index Order (index_column_b, index_column_a)
Swap Index Order
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS test_rows_a_b;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_rows_b_a ON test_rows (index_column_b, index_column_a);

Explain Plans
10,000 rows
Index Scan using test_rows_b_a on public.test_rows  (cost=0.57..20599.33 rows=10360 width=20) (actual time=0.025..7.480 rows=10000 loops=1)
  Output: index_column_a, index_column_b, value_column_a, value_column_b
  Index Cond: ((test_rows.index_column_b >= 0) AND (test_rows.index_column_b <= 9999) AND (test_rows.index_column_a = 5))
  Buffers: shared hit=913
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=10
Planning Time: 0.102 ms
Execution Time: 8.227 ms

100,000 rows
Index Scan using test_rows_b_a on public.test_rows  (cost=0.57..193696.92 rows=103555 width=20) (actual time=0.025..84.704 rows=100000 loops=1)
  Output: index_column_a, index_column_b, value_column_a, value_column_b
  Index Cond: ((test_rows.index_column_b >= 0) AND (test_rows.index_column_b <= 99999) AND (test_rows.index_column_a = 5))
  Buffers: shared hit=9105
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning Time: 0.095 ms
Execution Time: 92.357 ms

Analysis
As the explain plans show, queries for a single value of index_column_a and a range of index_column_b perform better with an index having order (index_column_a, index_column_b) rather than order (index_column_b, index_column_a). The difference in performance is a direct result of the number of blocks required to process the query. Having index_column_a as the first column of the index reduces the number of referenced blocks when searching based on a single value of index_column_a because rows with the same index_column_a are grouped together.
Recommended Column Order
Even though the order (index_column_a, index_column_b) performs better when querying for a single value of index_column_a, I recommend indexing with order (index_column_b, index_column_a) because it is likely that most queries will involve a small range of values for index_column_b and this column order is likely to be sufficiently performant regardless of the range of index_column_a values selected. When index_column_a is the first column of the index, the performance diminishes significantly as more values of index_column_a are queried.
To demonstrate this, run the following query with each index column order:
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE)
SELECT *
  FROM test_rows
  WHERE index_column_a BETWEEN 5 AND 6
    AND index_column_b bETWEEN 0 AND 9999;

Explain Plans
Index Order (index_column_a, index_column_b)
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.test_rows  (cost=511487.13..574934.41 rows=18308 width=20) (actual time=1587.625..1598.439 rows=20000 loops=1)
  Output: index_column_a, index_column_b, value_column_a, value_column_b
  Recheck Cond: ((test_rows.index_column_a >= 5) AND (test_rows.index_column_a <= 6) AND (test_rows.index_column_b >= 0) AND (test_rows.index_column_b <= 9999))
  Heap Blocks: exact=636
  Buffers: shared read=55284
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_rows_a_b  (cost=0.00..511482.56 rows=18308 width=0) (actual time=1585.735..1585.736 rows=20000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((test_rows.index_column_a >= 5) AND (test_rows.index_column_a <= 6) AND (test_rows.index_column_b >= 0) AND (test_rows.index_column_b <= 9999))
        Buffers: shared read=54648
Planning Time: 0.065 ms
Execution Time: 1599.845 ms

Index Order (index_column_b, index_column_a)
Index Scan using test_rows_b_a on public.test_rows  (cost=0.57..38717.34 rows=20730 width=20) (actual time=0.029..11.410 rows=20000 loops=1)
  Output: index_column_a, index_column_b, value_column_a, value_column_b
  Index Cond: ((test_rows.index_column_b >= 0) AND (test_rows.index_column_b <= 9999) AND (test_rows.index_column_a >= 5) AND (test_rows.index_column_a <= 6))
  Buffers: shared hit=913
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=10
Planning Time: 0.107 ms
Execution Time: 12.956 ms

